# Print function is returning the error elem.cloneNode is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function to print the form as follows:

```
document.getElementById("btnPrint").onclick = function () {
 printElement(document.getElementsByClassName("printThis"));
}

function printElement(elem) {
 var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);
                                
 var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");
                                
  if (!$printSection) {
    var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
    $printSection.id = "printSection";
    document.body.appendChild($printSection);
  }
                                
  $printSection.innerHTML = "";
  $printSection.appendChild(domClone);
  window.print();
}
```

When I run the function, it returns the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: elem.cloneNode is not a function
> at printElement
> at HTMLButtonElement.document.getElementById.onclick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending a `NodeList` instead of a `Node`, you should modify your second line with:

```
printElement(document.getElementsByClassName("printThis")[0]);
```